# Can't pass Eloquent model to Laravel Job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

I'm following the documentation for Laravel to pass an Eloquent model to a Laravel Job. However, despite my best efforts, I can't pass the Eloquent model - it is always "undefined" or another weird error.

This is for a Laravel 5.7 application, currently running on MacOS/Darwin, MySQL 5.5, and PHP 7.2. This job is launched from another job. I have one job which then dispatches many sub-jobs.

```
// From the Job itself
public function __construct(\App\Course $courseToDB)
{
    $this->courseToDB = $courseToDB;
}

public function handle(App\Course $courseToDB)
{        
    Log::info($this->courseToDB);
}
// From where I am dispatching the job
\App\Jobs\syncCourse::dispatch($courseToDB)->onConnection('database');
```

I expect that, when I dispatch the job with `$courseToDB` (an \App\Course model), the job will be able to pick that model up and, well, do things with it. The problem I have is that it will not pass the model to the job. Trying to use it even in the simplest logging scenario fails.

**Update: My Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'category_id', 'teacher_id', 'moodle_id', 'summary'];

    public function teacher() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher');
    }
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
    public function views() {
        return $this->morphMany(
            \App\view::class,
            'viewable'
        );
    }
// A few other functions cut out (very simple one-liners)

}
```

**Update: My Migration**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCoursesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('moodle_id');
            $table->integer('teacher_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->longText('summary')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('courses');
    }
}
```

**Update: My Job (syncCourse), which even when doing nothing fails**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Course;

class syncCourse implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $courseToDB;

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Course $courseToDB)
    {
        //\App\Course $courseToDB
        $this->courseToDB = $courseToDB;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {        

    }
}
```

**Update: From Terminal (when running)**

```
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3891] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3891] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3892] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3892] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3893] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3893] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3894] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3894] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3895] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3895] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3896] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3896] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3897] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3897] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3898] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3898] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3899] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3899] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3900] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3900] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3901] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3901] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3902] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3902] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3903] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3903] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3904] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3904] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3905] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3905] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3906] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3906] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3907] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 01:51:28][3907] Failed:     App\Jobs\syncCourse
```

In my app, `dispatchSync` dispatches hundreds of `syncCourse` and passes an Eloquent model. Passing the Eloquent model is what is broken, because even if I do absolutely *nothing* with the passed model, it errors. Laravel.log has zero trace of an error.

**UPDATE 2: After running Logging in Service Provider**

After turning on the logging in the service provider, all of the syncCourse events just went unfinished. Now my `queue:work` looks like this:

```
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5829] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5830] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5831] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5832] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5833] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5834] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5835] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5836] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5837] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5838] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5839] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5840] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5841] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5842] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5843] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5844] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5845] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5846] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5847] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5848] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5849] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5850] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5851] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5852] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5853] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5854] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5855] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5856] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
[2018-12-23 02:10:41][5857] Processing: App\Jobs\syncCourse
```

In the logs:

```
[2018-12-23 02:10:34] local.ERROR: database
[2018-12-23 02:10:34] local.ERROR: Object of class Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob could not be converted to string {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Object of class Illuminate\\Queue\\J
```

Comment: Do you get any error or log messages? If you have, please add in the question.

Comment: please post the full code of your job, especially the traits.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use as below,

Add `use \App\Course;` above the class declaration.

Inside your method call the model using `Course::function_name()`

In your model function declaration has to like `public static function function_name()`

Or share the error which is you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to debug where it went wrong. Here is the [complete reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs) on how to do it.

1.To create a migration for the `failed_jobs` table, you may use the `queue:failed-table` command:

> ```
>    php artisan queue:failed-table
>
>    php artisan migrate
> ```

2. Include the following method after `handle()` method.

   ```
   public function failed(Exception $exception)
   {
      //Your expection
      dd($exception)
   }
   ```